# Detecting Multiple Boxes in Object Detection using Tensorflow in Android App

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to train my custom model for detecting "Raccoon" in the Android App with **ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config**. I have used **ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29** pre-trained model. After 20K training steps, I am getting successfully `frozen_inference_graph.pb` file. But when I used this file in my Android App result is not accurate. I am getting multiple boxes with 0.99 accuracies not only on Raccoon but also on others objects. Besides **ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29**, i tried lots of pre-trained models.

Please help if anyone faced this problem.

[image: I have also attached the output screen]